# How to categorize subset of values in SQL Case condition

Tags: sql

I'm dealing with SQL case problem.

Scenario: Lets say I've got a customers table with only two values

Table: Customers
Column: Name

Name

1. John
2. Johnny

Now, I want to categorize them into bins. All names with 'John' will be marked as Group A and Group B for Johnny.

Expected Output

Name, Group

1. John, A
2. Johnny, B

I tried writing this SQL query,

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN first_name LIKE '%John%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN first_name LIKE '%Johnny%' THEN 'B'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Group
FROM Customers
```

But both the names were marked as 'A' since both name contain the word 'John'. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Remove the wildcard character atr the end of the first John: `WHEN first_name LIKE '%John' THEN 'A'`

Comment: Like John will find Johnny rows too. Switch order.

Comment: You can see that *john*-ny matches both, yes?

Comment: Why are using wild cards at all?

Comment: Those leading wildcards have rendered your query nonSARGable. Not sure you need wildcards here at all but at the very least you should get rid of the leading ones.

Comment: Here are the actual values:

Name
1. Product Name | SB | CAT | Platform Type | 
2. Product Name | SBV | CAT | Platform Type | 

Now even if I switch the order. The first case conditions value is marked for all the names.

Answer (score 0):

way not do = ?

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN first_name  = 'John' THEN 'A'
        WHEN first_name  = 'Johnny' THEN 'B'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Group
FROM Customers
```

Comment: Here are the actual values: 
Name 
1. Product Name | SB | CAT | Platform Type | 
2. Product Name | SBV | CAT | Platform Type | 

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN first_name  = 'SBV' THEN 'SBV'
        WHEN first_name  = 'SB' THEN 'SB'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Group
FROM Customers

Both of them will be categorized as SBV. Since it was the first condition in the case